# How to divide ElasticSearch query from beginning

Tags: elasticsearch

When execute query like this;

```
GET /library/books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "quick brown fox"
    }
  }
}
```

, it searches `"quick" or "brown" or "fox"`.

But I wanna search by `"quick" or "quick brown" or "quick brown fox"`,

because I don't need just "brown fox".

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using `match_phrase`:

```
GET /library/books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "quick"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "quick brown"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "quick brown fox"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this works, but is there any ways to change directly how the query is analyzed?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I wonder if there is some settings to to divide query automatically like above.

Comment: Using the [edge ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) in a custom analyzer might get you what you need.

Comment: Thank you! edge ngram into the query is what I need!